# Why am I getting an Invalid Syntax Error in the elif line?

Tags: python

Can someone please tell me why I am getting an invalid syntax error here(python 3):

```
a = input("Do you want the alphabets in the pattern in ascending order or descending order? (Yes/No) ")
if a == "Yes" or "yes":
    b = 65
    elif a == "No" or "no":
        b = 88
    else print("Invalid input")
for x in range (5,0,-1):
    for y in range (0,x):
        print(" ", chr(y+b), end = "")
    print()
```

Comment: because the indentation is incorrect, although even if it weren't it still wouldn't ever be reached because `or "yes"` will always be true

Comment: `a == "Yes" or "yes"` always returns True. You probably meant `a in ("Yes", "yes")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is the indention. `elif` and `else` have to be aligned with their respective `if`. Furthermore, after the `else` a `:` is expected and the result in the line below. Here I changed your code to make it functional:

```
a = input("Do you want the alphabets in the pattern in ascending order or descending order? (Yes/No) ")
if a.lower() == 'yes':
    b = 65
elif a.lower() == 'no':
    b = 88
else:
    print("Invalid input")
for x in range (5,0,-1):
    for y in range (0,x):
        print(" ", chr(y+b), end = "")
    print()
```

Comment: You could use `if a in {'Yes', 'yes'}:` or even better `if a.lower() = 'yes':`. And the next issue: `b` is not set in the `else` part, so `chr(y+b)` will crash later.

Comment: Yes is a big room for improvement, I was ensuring functionality.  I'll edit the answer to improve it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your issue is that the else statement is not complete. You are missing a colon(:) to end the condition part of your if-elif-else statement. Since the else statement is the catch-all condition, you would just need to immediately put a colon after else statement. So if your going for a one-liner else, which I wouldn't recommend because it slightly diminishes readability of your code, then you could do something like this:

```
a = input("Do you want the alphabets in the pattern in ascending order or descending order? (Yes/No) ")
if a == "Yes" or "yes":
    b = 65
elif a == "No" or "no":
    b = 88
else: print("Invalid input")

for x in range (5,0,-1):
    for y in range (0,x):
        print(" ", chr(y+b), end = "")
    print()
```

Secondly, how the conditions are written is not correct as it will ALWAYS evaluate to True. This is because the equality operator is a binary operator and the right side of the expression can be read as two separate expression. Here is a quick demonstration:

```
>>> a = "No"
>>> a == "Yes" or "yes"
>>> 'yes'
```

This because the result of your condition will always output 'yes' and Python boolean will always output True for a non-empty string:

```
>>> bool(a == "Yes" or "yes")
>>> True
```

At minimum you should put parenthesis around the right side of the comparison operation, so it can evaluate the entire right side.

```
>>> a == ("Yes" or "yes")
>>> False
```

On a side note, if the b is not declared prior to your if-else statement, you would likely run into issues with your for loop. It would prompt an error saying that you're using a variable before it was declared. In order for it to work properly, you need to ensure that b is declared in all conditions. So I would do something like this.

```
a = input("Do you want the alphabets in the pattern in ascending order or descending order? (Yes/No) ")
if a == "Yes" or "yes":
    b = 65
elif a == "No" or "no":
    b = 88
else: 
    b = 0
    print("Invalid input")

for x in range (5,0,-1):
    for y in range (0,x):
        print(" ", chr(y+b), end = "")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete your `or` statements. Python doesn't keep the `a ==` from the section before the `or`, so the section you write after the `or` is basically saying if "yes", which obviously doesn't make sense. To correct it, you need to change `if a == "Yes" or "yes":` to `if a == "Yes" or a == "yes":` and do the same with your elif statement.

Also, make sure you don't leave the indentation from the if statement, as it puts the elif and else statments as something which happens after the if is triggered. Make sure that they are in line with the if statement. Plus, remember that else statements are like if/elif statements in that you need to close the statement with a colon, then put what you want to happen indented under - `else:`, then the next line.

```
if a == "Yes" or a == "yes":
    b = 88
elif a== "No" or "no":
    b == 88
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

I hope that makes sense as I don't often answer questions, but I try to help when I can.